# How to prepend to the the existing elements in a list?

Tags: jquery, list, append

I'm appending some items dynamically to an unordered list, but the jQuery `.append()` function only appends to the bottom of the list, like this:

> - Appended 1
> - Appended 2
> - Appended 3
> - Appended 4

But what I want to do is append like this:

> - Appended 4
> - Appended 3
> - Appended 2
> - Appended 1

How can I do this?

Comment: jQuery documentation is available at http://api.jquery.com.  The `prepend` documentation can be found further down the page in the section (Manipulation) containing the `append` documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to *ap*-pend, you want to *pre*-pend! For this, funnily enough, you can use the [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend) method.

```
$('ul').prepend('<li>Prepended 1</li').prepend('<li>Prepended 2</li>');
```

Comment: Oh thanks very much. My english is bad so I couldn't had thought on this. Sorry